# PhoneNumbers was not found

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to create a proxy for two phones to communicate via text. I can create the service  but when I try to create the phone number twilio tells me it can not be found. I am using the Phone ID from the console. The number can send and receive a text fine.

Ive read all the forums, and verified  that I am using the phone SID

```
$service = $client->proxy->v1->services->create($_POST['SmsMessageSid']);

$phone_number = $client->proxy->v1->services($service)->phoneNumbers->create(array("sid" => 'PHONE SSID'));
```

The error I get is:

> Error: [HTTP 404] Unable to create record: The requested resource /Services/[Twilio.Proxy.V1.ServiceInstance sid=whatever]/PhoneNumbers was not found

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The method `$client->proxy->v1->services` takes the `sid` as a parameter and not a `ServiceInstance` object. To fix this you would need to pass the `$service->sid` instead.

```
$phone_number = $client->proxy->v1->services($service->sid)->phoneNumbers->create(array("sid" => 'PHONE SSID'));
```

Let me know if that helps at all.